# Android studio status bar position

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

A friend recently moved from iOS development to Android development. I found out that he always misses when gradle is building or when Android Studio is indexing files. 
The problem is that the status bar is at the bottom and is barely visible. Is there a way to move the status bar in the top area of the IDE?

I need to move the red bordered area to the top. For example right above the navigation bar. [image: statusbarandroidstudio]

Is it possible in any way?

Comment: hi Luca, unfortunately there's no such a placement option so far. What is exactly your primary problem? in other words I don't understand what do you mean by "he always misses when gradle is building or when Android Studio is indexing files". Personally I don't see any problem with that placement, and also I am using intellij with completely disabling seeing status bar.

Comment: I would like to move it to the top of the IDE. In the status bar you can see which task is being performed, like "running", "installing apk", etc. And I would like it to be more visible, not placed at the bottom of the screen